# items squeezed in ng-repeat with flexbox - angular.js/flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to let a container be scrollable if the content is filled with ng-repeat using flexbox.

The problem seems to be that flexbox doesn't apply any height to its elements.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='item' ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class='item-inner'>{{item.text}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eg2zn2d/

In the fiddle you see items get squeezed together.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Seems to work fine

Comment: just realized its working for me too in firefox. but not in opera ( 41.0.2353.69) and chrome (Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)).

Comment: Works fine in chrome and firefox for me

Comment: Probably a browser issue. Which versions are you using. Can you try upgrading your browser?

Comment: Opera (Version 41.0.2353.69) and Chrome (Version 54.0.2840.100). I prefer not to solve the problem by upgrading my browser.

Comment: nashcheez's answer is correct. But if you want an alternate option then just place "container" div in a parent div. Make container height as auto and place height boundary on parent of container.  http://jsfiddle.net/5eg2zn2d/2/#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you can add `flex-shrink: 0;` to your `.item` element for browsers that do not properly support the dynamic addition of elements inside the flexbox.

So your code becomes:

```
.item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 3px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```